# French loanwords ending in "-tion"

Tags: этимология, лексикон, заимствования

I've noticed that, not only in Russian, but in many other Eastern European languages that in French loanwords that end in "-tion", the suffix almost always appears as "-cija" (-ция). Examples include words like "informacija". I've tried to look up the etymology of the suffix to no avail.

My question is, is "-cija" a native Slavic suffix or is it a phonetic rendering of the original French suffix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-ция" is a rendering of Latin "-tio" rather than French "-tion". Even though some words were borrowed from French (actually in Russian many loan words were borrowed indirectly through Polish), they became "Latin"-lookalike in Russian.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement Matt's answer. Your assumption is indeed false, first set of words with "-ция" was not derived from French words but rather from their Latin cognates - through Polish - for instance words `навигация`, `революция`, `нация`, `милиция`, `конструкция`, `акция` are corresponding to Polish `nawigacja`, `rewolucja`, `nасjа`, `milicja`, `konstrukcja`, `akcja`.

Then some words were derived from French (or English which was influenced by French and also have -tion) but the tradition to keep "-ция" for "-tion" preserved.

As of why Latin `-tion` morphed into [cja](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-cja) - it's better ask at Polish-related Stack. Which, unfortunately, does not exist so far.

Comment: милиция was already militia in Latin, not militio.